# Bash parser and find duplicates by condition

Tags: bash

I need parse a log file, for example:

```
    151.67.79.39/mnt3/WkJWwe3eYp/2w8PNGLrBh/158
    95.245.46.253/storage1/FV3QLXuaDG/PlfwC4BtV9/254
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
    87.17.174.236/storage1/IDtx9c2p7i/VwTNiwHAJF/255
    87.17.174.236/storage1/IDtx9c2p7i/VwTNiwHAJF/255
    87.17.174.118/storage1/IDtx9c2p7i/VwTNiwHAJF/255
    87.17.174.236/storage1/IDtx9c2p7i/VwTNiwHAJF/255
    87.161.130.61/storage1/IDtx9c2p7i/VwTNiwHAJF/255
    62.43.164.247/storage1/eDoT6fI4vp/76GwaRzJCL/31
    93.229.17.99/mnt3/uQi9iiyMZA/G83FZV2zCB/160
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
    93.40.125.31/storage1/4mN9uJGwA2/0uOM39Gx8g/10
    95.245.46.253/storage1/FV3QLXuaDG/PlfwC4BtV9/254
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
    87.17.174.236/storage1/IDtx9c2p7i/VwTNiwHAJF/255
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
    95.245.46.253/storage1/FV3QLXuaDG/PlfwC4BtV9/254
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
    94.38.149.210/storage1/RXhISkEsOw/AHwro83Lyp/97
    95.245.46.253/storage1/FV3QLXuaDG/PlfwC4BtV9/254
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
    95.245.46.253/storage1/FV3QLXuaDG/PlfwC4BtV9/254
    151.75.214.206/storage1/DeOq0ej9B2/fr48SLpuri/80
...
```

[IP]/[ITEM1]/[ITEM2]/[ITEM3]/[ITEM4]

I need to find all IPs that have the same ITEM2.
Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ tr -d ' ' <file | awk -F"/" -vOFS=, '
        {a[$3]=a[$3]?a[$3] OFS $1:$1} 
     END{for(i in a) print i":"a[i]}'
```

will print

```
RXhISkEsOw:94.38.149.210
uQi9iiyMZA:93.229.17.99
FV3QLXuaDG:95.245.46.253,95.245.46.253,95.245.46.253,95.245.46.253,95.245.46.253
eDoT6fI4vp:62.43.164.247
IDtx9c2p7i:87.17.174.236,87.17.174.236,87.17.174.118,87.17.174.236,87.161.130.61,87.17.174.236
4mN9uJGwA2:93.40.125.31
WkJWwe3eYp:151.67.79.39
DeOq0ej9B2:151.75.214.206,151.75.214.206,151.75.214.206,151.75.214.206,151.75.214.206,151.75.214.206,151.75.214.206
```

the first `tr` is to delete the spaces in your input file, if your file is clean you can remove that

**UPDATE** 
if you want all UNIQUE IPs instead of ALL IPs, it's a different task but `awk` is up to it.

```
$ tr -d ' ' <file | awk -F"/" -vOFS=, '
       {k=$3 FS $1} 
  !d[k]{a[$3]=a[$3]?a[$3] OFS $1:$1;d[k]++} 
    END{for(i in a) print i":"a[i]}'
```

will result (here uniqueness is defined within the context of ITEM2)

```
RXhISkEsOw:94.38.149.210
uQi9iiyMZA:93.229.17.99
FV3QLXuaDG:95.245.46.253
eDoT6fI4vp:62.43.164.247
IDtx9c2p7i:87.17.174.236,87.17.174.118,87.161.130.61
4mN9uJGwA2:93.40.125.31
WkJWwe3eYp:151.67.79.39
DeOq0ej9B2:151.75.214.206
```

**UPDATE 2**

I'm hoping you're not preparing specs for programmers :)

If you need the list of unique IPs for ITEM2 when the list size is greater than 1.

```
$ tr -d ' ' <file | awk -F"/" -vOFS=, '
      {k=$3 FS $1} 
 !d[k]{a[$3]=a[$3]?a[$3] OFS $1:$1;d[k]++;c[$3]++} 
   END{for(i in a) if(c[i]>1) print i":"a[i]}'
```

will print

```
IDtx9c2p7i:87.17.174.236,87.17.174.118,87.161.130.61
```

if you don't need the item prefix delete `i":"` from the print statement.  Or if you need a different separator than comma change `OFS` value.

Comment: Thanks for answer karakfa. Can you tell me how to get ONLY all ITEM2 that have different IP (without duplicates) ?

Comment: For example: in my sample log, only ITEM2 "IDtx9c2p7i" has multiple different IP, so I want to get only: 87.17.174.236/IDtx9c2p7i, 87.17.174.118/IDtx9c2p7i/, 87.17.174.236/IDtx9c2p7i/, 87.161.130.61/IDtx9c2p7i/

Comment: please see the update.

Comment: OK now is good ;) But Is there a way to exclude others? I need ONLY all IPs that has the same ITEM2, so in your example, only: 87.17.174.236,87.17.174.118,87.161.130.61 .. but i need to have separated IP to execute a command (iptables)

Comment: @StefanoGuarella : for crying out loud, if you're so off in your problem definition, post a new question! Arg!!!! ;-)   ... Good luck.